# How to trigger an executable installed on azure vm through a function app

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-virtual-machine

I am looking for a way to trigger or run an executable daily at a specific time on azure virtual machine through function app. Is there a way azure function app can talk to virtual machine?

Going through samples on microsoft learn site I didnt find any way to do this. I can try adding it to task scheduler but it will be difficult to manage in production and view logs or start/stop service as team has limited access in production.

Comment: You can trigger a PowerShell script that would then be able to trigger the executable. Have a look at “Automation” as well. LogicApps too. There may be something there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use azure PowerShell timer trigger function to run executables at a given time.

- Here you need to create a function app using PowerShell core:

[image]

Then create the azure function.
Open Function App and then click on Functions and click on Create:

[image]

Then click on Timer Trigger and then set the time interval you want as below:

[image]

Then open the created function:

[image]

PowerShell [Script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/run-command) to run on VM.
As an Alternative you can use Automations and Logic apps as @Skin Commented.

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to run azure cli commands to run command on virtual machine?